# JQuery: Syntax assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I have 2 lists that are the exact same. When I mouse over 1 of the lists, I want the items from both lists to be slightly opaque.

I have used JavaScript many times; however, not recently. I historically refused to use JQuery until I was relatively familiar with JavaScript. Now I figured I'd give it a try to re-make something I made a while ago but I'm not completely sure that I'm doing it correctly.

I have this code that is supposed to find all li elements in a ul with a class of navlist whose text matches the one that was moused over, and set it's opacity to 0.7. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Any ideas on why would be appreciated.

```
$(".NavList li:contains('" + $(lbutt).text() + "')").css("opacity:0.7;");
```

edit:
This code is within a function. When a link is moused over it passes "this" to lbutt.

edit#2:
The google developer console doesn't throw any errors.

edit#3:
The answer:

```
$(".NavList li:contains('" + $(lbutt).text() + "')").css("opacity","0.7");
```

Comment: That was already edited in above :P

Comment: Your argument to `css()` is incorrect. Please consult [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Frederic thank you so much, it works now. Could you do me a favor and post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle that shows how to do something similar here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAvDN/

HTML:

```
<ul class="hoverme">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>

<ul class="navlist">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".hoverme li").hover(function() {
    var what = $(this).text();
    $(".navlist li:contains('" + what + "')").css("color", "red");
}, function() {
    $(".navlist li").css("color", "black");
});
```

The main syntax mistake I'm seeing is that you're using `.css("opacity:0.7")` instead of `.css("opacity", "0.7")`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$('.YourClass li').hover(function(){
var txt = $(this).text(); // get the text of hovered element
$('NavList li').each(function(){ // loop through your li elements to check if text is the same
    if ($(this).text() == txt){
        $(this).css('opacity','0.7'); // set your CSS rules
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @samitha, your edit introduced a syntax error. Arguments are delimited by commas, not colons. You also removed all comments, I don't know why.

Comment: I tried to do this first and got it to work but found it ugly. The above line works now but because yours "could" have been a solution I gave you a +1